# Handsontable: setDataAtCell on the trigger of an event

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, handsontable

I am new to handsontable library of Javascript and hence apologize if the question seems too basic.

What I am trying to do is that if someone writes /changes the data written in the first row of the table, the value in the cell at column 5 and row 5 should be set to "changed". I know that to set a value I would need to use `hot.setDataAtCell(5,5,"changed")`. What I don't know is how to trigger this command i.e. I need to find a way to identify when any cell in the first row of a column has been changed. I have tried overriding the `afterChange` callback, but the code keeps on hanging.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8hv4z/18/, something similar to this?

Comment: Hi. Just tried out the code. Apparently this code works fine, but if I add the command hot.setDataAtCell(5, 5,"33"); inside the afterChange function, it stops working. 'hot' is the name of my handsontable. Do you have any idea of why this thing is happening? The same command works fine, if I add it outside everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem,

Example:

```
 var cellChanges = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    var myData = [{
        0: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa',
        1: 'bbbbbbbbb',
        2: 'ccccccc'
    }, {
        0: 'aaaa',
        1: 'b',
        2: 'bbbb'
    }, {
        0: 'aaaa',
        1: 'x',
        2: 'bbbb'
    }, {
        0: 'aaaa',
        1: 'w',
        2: 'bbbb'
    }, ];

    $("#editOrders").handsontable({
        data: myData,

        autoWrapRow: true,
        minSpareRows: true,
        columnSorting: true,
        fillHandle: false,
        currentRowClassName: 'currentRow',
        colHeaders: ["demo", "demo", "demo"],
        afterChange: function (changes, source) {
            if (!changes) {
                return;
            }
            $.each(changes, function (index, element) {
                var change = element;
                var rowIndex = change[0];
                var columnIndex = change[1];

                var oldValue = change[2];
                var newValue = change[3];

                var cellChange = {
                    'rowIndex': rowIndex,
                    'columnIndex': columnIndex
                };

                if(oldValue != newValue){
                    cellChanges.push(cellChange);
                }
            });
        },
        afterRender: function () {
            var instance = $('#editOrders').handsontable('getInstance');
            $.each(cellChanges, function (index, element) {
                var cellChange = element;
                var rowIndex = cellChange['rowIndex'];
                var columnIndex = cellChange['columnIndex'];
                var cell = instance.getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                var foreColor = '#000';
                var backgroundColor = '#ff00dd';
                cell.style.color = foreColor;
                cell.style.background = backgroundColor;
            });
        },
        columns: [{
            //LINE
            data: 0
        }, {
            //LINE
            data: 1
        }, {
            //LINE
            data: 2
        },

        ]
    });

});
```

and here is the link to jsfiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/8hv4z/18/

Answer (score 2):

`setDataAtCell()` does not seem to work inside the afterChange callback function.

The way to do it is to use an initialized variable for data while initializing the handsontable like *data: mydata* and then the afterChange function should look like this:

```
afterChange: function (changes, source) {
    mydata[5][5]="changed";

    this.render();
}
```

Comment: the reason being that setDataAtCell triggers the afterChange event. it would throw it into an endless loop :) so I assume handson is smart enough to catch that

Comment: yes that was the sole reason for the code not working. :-)

Comment: yup, gotta be careful with the events in handson, they're very powerful. something to remember is that most handson methods WILL trigger the afterChange event. To get around this you should do what you did here and manually change your data source, without any handson methods